# Depuración errónea al pasar el contador de programa por sscanf

Tags: c, conversión-de-tipos

Programo un micro stm32f205, tengo que hacer una conversión de la siguiente forma:

Si tengo

```
uint8_t num[2] = {{0x34}, {0x46}}, RegRec2Overwrite;
```

Tengo que obtener

```
RegRec2Overwrite = 0x4F;
```

Estoy haciendo:

```
sscanf((char*)&num, "%02x", &RegRec2Overwrite);                 //hex conversion
```

Pero depurando, cuando el contador de programa pasa por `sscanf`, se me reinician todas las variables globales del archivo que necesariamente tengo que usar. No tengo ni idea por qué pasa esto. He usado STM32CubeMx para generar el código de partida, las librerías tienen copyright de 2018.

Si alguien me puede ayudar o dar cualquier información se lo agradecería.

Comment: Creo que así será suficiente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Pero depurando, cuando el contador de programa pasa por sscanf, se me reinician todas las variables globales del archivo que necesariamente tengo que usar

Este es un síntoma de que en alguna parte de tu código estás pisando memoria.  Vamos a ver uno de los mensajes que te aparecen al compilar:

> warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int *' but the argument has type 'uint8_t *'

Más claro el agua... `%x` almacena el resultado en un `unsigned int` (4 bytes) y tu le estás facilitando un `uint8_t` (1 byte). Al llamar a `sscanf` se van a sobreescribir 3 bytes que no pertenecen a `RegRec2Overwrite` y que, visto lo visto, pertenecen a variables ¿globales? (por favor, evita el uso de variables globales).

Un cambio sencillo para resolver el aviso:

```
unsigned int RegRec2Overwrite;
```

Y por arte de magia el valor almacenado en esta variable pasa a ser el 79... que traducido a hexadecimal se convierte en 0x4F... y además ahora ya no se machaca el valor de otras variables.

Comment: Hola muy buenas!! Es cierto que estaba pisando memoria. Tengo problemas con la conversión y además arrastraba varios warning de antes. Voy a reducir el número de variables globales, siempre ocuparán menos RAM ¿No? Mil gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @JotaCorp si estás trabajando con un 16 MB de RAM pues sí, eliminar variables suele reducir el consumo de memoria... pero en un equipo con 16GB de RAM... como que no se va a notar mucho. El peligro de las variables globales tiene que ver más con la dificultad para controlar su acceso y su ciclo de vida. Por cierto, si esta incidencia resuelve tu problema no olvides marcarla como solución. Gracias

Comment: trabajo con un STM32F205 son poco más de 128K creo, pero en cualquier caso me parecería interesante saber más sobre el control y el ciclo de vida de una variable global, ya que en estos micros hay que reducir su uso y conocer su ciclo. Si conoces alguna referencia sobre este tema te lo agradecería.

Comment: @JotaCorp las referencias son reducir el tiempo de vida de las variables al mínimo imprescindible, evitar el uso de variables globales en la medida de lo posible, tener clara y estudiada la arquitectura del sistema antes de ponerse a programar y pensárselo dos veces antes de introducir cambios una vez empezado el desarrollo... hay más detallitos pero dudo que encuentres una guía en la que te detalle este tipo de causísticas... la experiencia y el orden son dos factores bastante importantes

Comment: me sirve!! Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Además de los problemas de tamaño que te señala la respuesta de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/463/eferion), tienes otro error que puede ser causa de tus problemas, y que en todo caso tienes que corregir.

La función `sscanf()` espera que su primer argumento sea una *cadena*, y esto en C es un array de caracteres *terminado con un cero*. Tu array no es de `char`, sus elementos son en realidad `uint_8`, pero ya que ocupan 1 byte cada uno, lo mismo que un `char`, esto no da problemas. El verdadero problema es la ausencia del cero final.

`sscanf()`, al igual que el resto de funciones de manejo de cadenas del C (en `string.h`) reciben en general un puntero al inicio de la cadena, pero no saben cuántos caracteres la componen. Todas ellas van leyendo bytes desde esa dirección en adelante, hasta encontrarse un byte de valor cero que les indica que la cadena se ha terminado. Sin el terminador, seguirán leyendo más allá de las direcciones donde estaba la cadena, invadiendo otras variables, hasta que finalmente, tarde o temprano, encuentren una posición de memoria en que hay un cero, y se detengan, o una posición de memoria protegida, y el sistema operativo les detenga con un *segfault*.

Solución, añade ese cero final:

```
uint8_t num[3] = {{0x34}, {0x46}, {0}},
```

Comment: No necesariamente... `sscanf` no tiene por qué recorrer todo el buffer de entrada sino que procesa lo mínimo requerido por los parámetros de lectura... en este caso con los dos bytes es suficiente y ahí deja de leer. En lo que sí coincido contigo es en que es más seguro... pero con `%02x` no es necesario finalizar la cadena

Comment: Es cierto que funciona correctamente tal cual dice eferion. En cualquier caso es interesante esta información abulafia ya que creo que sí que ha sido fuente de algunos de mis problemas en el pasado. Este {0} último al que te refieres supongo que será el caracter NULL en ASCII (El primer valor de la tabla de ASCII) ¿no?

Comment: @JotaCorp exacto, el caracter `\0` es equivalente a `(char)0`

Comment: Perfecto @abulafia, mil gracias de nuevo.